# How to invoke web api method from client side in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a sample asp.net core application and I chose MVC template while creating the project. Now I added a new API controller as below. How can I call this web api from jquery?

I tried 'api/TestAPI/GetTest' which does not work. I get 404 Not found error. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
[Route("api/TestAPI")]
[ApiController]
public class TestAPIController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]

    public ActionResult GetTest()
    {
        return new OkResult();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is related with how asp net core routes the requests.There are different ways to config how to handle requests to actions in your controllers (for more info go to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)), in case you want to use the name of the methods of your action , you can use the `Route` attribute as you did before on your controller  but adding the action part:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class TestAPIController : ControllerBase
```

Answer (score 1):

With current configuration `GET` request with `api/TestAPI` url will hit `GetTest` action. If you want to use `api/TestAPI/GetTest` url add `GetTest` route to the action

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetTest")]
public ActionResult GetTest()
{
    return new OkResult();
}
```

or using shortcut

```
[HttpGet("GetTest")]
public ActionResult GetTest()
{
    return new OkResult();
}
```